# Profile fields in Advanced User Management module - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am developing a site in drupal 7.14, and I have installed the **Advanced User Management** module of version *7.x-3.0-alpha2*. With this module I was able to filter out the users by username, email id etc. But in additional to these features, I need to add the profile fields (specifically, 'last name') and filter out the users according to the last name.

Anyone knows how to implement profile fields to this module? Any solution for this will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, users are entities, so you don't need a separate module for user management or profile fields.

Simply add fields to users similar to how you'd add them to content types, then build a custom management dashboard with views. You can expose the filters you want (by the fields you added to users).